Im unable to get MSW to fire off while running a Jest test in my react app
I have a feeling this is JEST running through the test too fast. But wanted to throw some feelers out there.
Here is my test file
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'; // Add this import
import { http, HttpResponse } from 'msw'
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { render, screen, prettyDOM } from '@testing-library/react'
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node'
import fs from "node:fs";
import Organizations from '../Organizations';
import React from 'react';
import store from "../../../globalStore/store";;

export const handlers = [
  http.get('/organizations/children', (req, res, ctx) => {
    console.log("DID THIS HIT?");
    return res(
      ctx.json({
        id: 'c7b3d8e0-5e0b-4b0f-8b3a-3b9f4b3d3b3d',
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Maverick',
      })
    );
  }),
];

const server = setupServer(...handlers)

// Enable API mocking before tests.
beforeAll(() => {
  server.listen()
})

// Reset any runtime request handlers we may add during the tests.
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers())

// Disable API mocking after the tests are done.
afterAll(() => {
  server.close()
  process.env = OLD_ENV; // Restore old environment
})

const OLD_ENV = process.env;

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.resetModules() // Most important - it clears the cache
  process.env = { ...OLD_ENV }; // Make a copy
});

test('handleDeleteOrganization function works correctly', async () => {
  process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT = 'https://example.com/';

  // Render the Organizations component
  render(<Provider
    store={store}
  >
    <Organizations apiUrl="" />
  </Provider>
  )


  // Check if datagrid renders
  expect(screen.getByRole('grid')).toBeInTheDocument();

});

The component that im testing has a init function that reaches out to a redux thunk that invokes a api call. Hence the MSW server implementation.
The api call fired off by the thunk looks something like this...
export const retrieveChildOrganizations = async (props) => {
  const apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT;

  console.log("We are inside of the retrieveChildOrganizations function")

  const results = await fetch(`${apiUrl}organizations/children`, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "auth-token": props.token
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log("HI 1")
      return res.json()
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log("HI 2")
      if (res.error) {
        return { error: res.error };
      }

      return res.organizations
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("HI 3")
      console.log(err);
      return { error: err };
    });

  console.log("HI 4")
  // return results;
  return null
};

You'll see that i've littered the API call with console logs.
The jest test is able to get to the first console log "We are inside of the..." but is unable to reach out to the rest.
When I comment out the "results" variable and return null I am able to reach the "Hi 4" console.log. Telling me that this has something to do with the await fetch. The console.log in MSW also never fires. Is this a race condition between Redux / Jest? Is there something I can add to my test to set this up properly?
If MSW is able to trigger and im able to control what payload is delivered to Jest i'll be golden after that!
